# How to add a class to custom tinymce toolbar menu item?

Tags: javascript, tinymce-4

I've added custom toolbar button for tinymce with image, I want to add a class to that. I've tried of adding class parameter but didnt work for me.
pls advice

```
  tinyMCE.PluginManager.add('subBtn', function(editor, url) {

        editor.addButton('subBtn', {
            class :'buttonClas',
            image: icon-path,
            icon: true,
            tooltip: tooltip,
            onclick: function() {
                // Open window
                editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'PTION',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox',value: subBtin, name: 'title', label: 'subBtn'}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {


                    }
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "classes" instead of "class" - you can add more than one, divided by spaces.

Comment: In Fiddle it works. I change:  
- 'class' to 'classes',  <br/>

- value: subBtin to value: 'subBtin',  

- delete image: icon-path, icon: true,  tooltip: tooltip, and add only text to represent button.  
See how it looks like: [fiddle.tinymce.com/bygaab](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/bygaab)

Comment: Ok, I can see now where it puts your class, it's in the outer <div> tag. But I wanted to find a way to change class in this tag *<span class="mce-txt">subBtnIcon</span>* in case when I don't use a text at all, just icon, for example "mce-ico mce-i-subscript" classes.

Comment: I can't see on documentation method to exactly do this. May I ask you: what do you need this class for?
Because if it's for styling purposes or script, you can use just more specific selector. On my next test, I add class, id and example icon. You can disable any of them (text, id, class or/and icon by commenting it with // or delete) and run your settings. In style section I add some basic css to show script behavior. There is this test: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/bygaab/3 .
TLDR: I don't know how to do it, but you can test ".mce-buttonClas .mce-ico", maybe it'll work for you.